# How to remove a word completely from a Word2Vec model in gensim?

Tags: python, dictionary, word2vec, gensim, del

Given a model, e.g.

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec


documents = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
"A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
"The EPS user interface management system",
"System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
"Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
"The generation of random binary unordered trees",
"The intersection graph of paths in trees",
"Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
"Graph minors A survey"]

texts = [d.lower().split() for d in documents]

w2v_model = Word2Vec(texts, size=5, window=5, min_count=1, workers=10)
```

It's possible to remove the word from the w2v vocabulary, e.g.

```
# Originally, it's there.
>>> print(w2v_model['graph'])
[-0.00401433  0.08862179  0.08601206  0.05281207 -0.00673626]

>>> print(w2v_model.wv.vocab['graph'])
Vocab(count:3, index:5, sample_int:750148289)

# Find most similar words.
>>> print(w2v_model.most_similar('graph'))
[('binary', 0.6781558990478516), ('a', 0.6284914612770081), ('unordered', 0.5971308350563049), ('perceived', 0.5612867474555969), ('iv', 0.5470727682113647), ('error', 0.5346164703369141), ('machine', 0.480206698179245), ('quasi', 0.256790429353714), ('relation', 0.2496253103017807), ('trees', 0.2276223599910736)]

# We can delete it from the dictionary
>>> del w2v_model.wv.vocab['graph']
>>> print(w2v_model['graph'])
KeyError: "word 'graph' not in vocabulary"
```

But when we do a similarity on other words after deleting `graph`, we see the word `graph` popping up, e.g.

```
>>> w2v_model.most_similar('binary')
[('unordered', 0.8710334300994873), ('ordering', 0.8463168144226074), ('perceived', 0.7764195203781128), ('error', 0.7316686511039734), ('graph', 0.6781558990478516), ('generation', 0.5770125389099121), ('computer', 0.40017056465148926), ('a', 0.2762695848941803), ('testing', 0.26335978507995605), ('trees', 0.1948457509279251)]
```

**How to remove a word completely from a Word2Vec model in gensim?**

---

## Updated

To answer @vumaasha's comment:

> could you give some details as to why you want to delete a word

- Lets say my universe of words in all words in the corpus to learn the dense relations between all words.
- But when I want to generate the similar words, it should only come from a subset of domain specific word.
- It's possible to generate more than enough from `.most_similar()` then filter the words but lets say the space of the specific domain is small, I might be looking for a word that's ranked 1000th most similar which is inefficient.
- It would be better if the word is totally removed from the word vectors then the `.most_similar()` words won't return words outside of the specific domain.

Comment: could you give some details as to why you want to delete a word

Comment: Sorry the motivation to delete a word is too long to type as a comment, see updated question. It shouldn't be hard to just remove a word totally from the embedding matrix. Just that there seems to be something I'm missing and not sure how it can be removed. Maybe it's because it's not possible to remove since the similarity is already sort of hard-baked into the huffman tree per word.

Comment: do you have a complete list of domain specific keywords that you want to get in similarity results?

Comment: Yes, I do. But please note that removing them before training would have removed the relations of the words outside of the domain, so that's not desirable. They have to be removed after training. Think of the model as a pre-trained model and it's meant to adapt to a domain but I'm not implying full-blown transfer learning here.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a function which removes words from KeyedVectors which aren't in a predefined word list.

```py
def restrict_w2v(w2v, restricted_word_set):
    new_vectors = []
    new_vocab = {}
    new_index2entity = []
    new_vectors_norm = []

    for i in range(len(w2v.vocab)):
        word = w2v.index2entity[i]
        vec = w2v.vectors[i]
        vocab = w2v.vocab[word]
        vec_norm = w2v.vectors_norm[i]
        if word in restricted_word_set:
            vocab.index = len(new_index2entity)
            new_index2entity.append(word)
            new_vocab[word] = vocab
            new_vectors.append(vec)
            new_vectors_norm.append(vec_norm)

    w2v.vocab = new_vocab
    w2v.vectors = new_vectors
    w2v.index2entity = new_index2entity
    w2v.index2word = new_index2entity
    w2v.vectors_norm = new_vectors_norm
```

It rewrites all of the variables which are related to the words based on the [Word2VecKeyedVectors](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py).

Usage:

```
w2v = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True)
w2v.most_similar("beer")
```

> [('beers', 0.8409687876701355),
>    ('lager', 0.7733745574951172),
>    ('Beer', 0.71753990650177),
>    ('drinks', 0.668931245803833),
>    ('lagers', 0.6570086479187012),
>    ('Yuengling_Lager', 0.655455470085144),
>    ('microbrew', 0.6534324884414673),
>    ('Brooklyn_Lager', 0.6501551866531372),
>    ('suds', 0.6497018337249756),
>    ('brewed_beer', 0.6490240097045898)]

```
restricted_word_set = {"beer", "wine", "computer", "python", "bash", "lagers"}
restrict_w2v(w2v, restricted_word_set)
w2v.most_similar("beer")
```

> [('lagers', 0.6570085287094116),
>    ('wine', 0.6217695474624634),
>    ('bash', 0.20583480596542358),
>    ('computer', 0.06677375733852386),
>    ('python', 0.005948573350906372)]

Comment: I don't know if the specs have changed since, but for readers using gensim 3.7.1, you have to keep vectors as numpy array, thus `w2v.vectors = numpy.array(new_vectors)`. Also, you need to call `w2v.init_sims()` before you call thish function. Last, save the model with `w2v.save_word2vec_format()`, not a usual `w2v.save()`, and load with `w2v.load_word2vec_format()` as shown in the answer. Thanks @zsozso for the cool function, and hope this helps any future readers.

Comment: if you want your model to be savable you must use numpy array. you can see saveable version of  code with a few more comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55725093/7339624.

Comment: Could the model be trained in an increased way after this rewrite?

Comment: Doesn't work for Gensim 4, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do what you are looking for. However, you are not completely lost. The method `most_similar` is implemented in the class [`WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f4354ce20468b61d9ea5495536d5b8da83565704/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L303) (check the link). You can take a look at this method and modify it to suit your needs.

The [lines](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f4354ce20468b61d9ea5495536d5b8da83565704/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L375) shown below perform the actual logic of computing the similar words, you need to replace the variable `limited` with vectors corresponding to words of your interest. Then you are done

```
limited = self.vectors_norm if restrict_vocab is None else self.vectors_norm[:restrict_vocab]
        dists = dot(limited, mean)
        if not topn:
            return dists
best = matutils.argsort(dists, topn=topn + len(all_words), reverse=True)
```

Update:

```
limited = self.vectors_norm if restrict_vocab is None else self.vectors_norm[:restrict_vocab]
```

If you see this line, it means if `restrict_vocab` is used it restricts top n words in the vocab, it is meaningful only if you have sorted the vocab by frequency. If you are not passing restrict_vocab, `self.vectors_norm` is what goes into limited

the method most_similar calls another method [`init_sims`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f4354ce20468b61d9ea5495536d5b8da83565704/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L343). This initializes the value for `[self.vector_norm][4]` like shown below

```
        self.vectors_norm = (self.vectors / sqrt((self.vectors ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)
```

so, you can pickup the words that you are interested in, prepare their norm and use it in place of limited. This should work

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly correct, we have to be careful here. `limited` here points to the `restrict_vocab` (https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L375)  which isn't a list of specified vocabulary but an integer point to limit the most-similar search, see https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L321

Answer (score 2):

Note that this does not trim the model per se. It trims the `KeyedVectors` object that the similarity look-ups is based on.

Suppose you only want to keep the top 5000 words in your model.

```
wv = w2v_model.wv
words_to_trim = wv.index2word[5000:]
# In op's case 
# words_to_trim = ['graph'] 
ids_to_trim = [wv.vocab[w].index for w in words_to_trim]

for w in words_to_trim:
    del wv.vocab[w]

wv.vectors = np.delete(wv.vectors, ids_to_trim, axis=0)
wv.init_sims(replace=True)

for i in sorted(ids_to_trim, reverse=True):
    del(wv.index2word[i])
```

This does the job because the [BaseKeyedVectors class](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py) contains the following attributes: self.vectors, self.vectors_norm, self.vocab, self.vector_size, self.index2word.

The advantage of this is that if you write the KeyedVectors using methods such as `save_word2vec_format()`, the file is much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Have tried and felt that the most straightforward way is as follows:

1. Get the Word2Vec embeddings in text file format.
2. Identify the lines corresponding to the word vectors that you would like to keep.
3. Write a new text file Word2Vec embedding model.
4. Load model and enjoy (save to binary if you wish, etc.)...

My sample code is as follows:

```
line_no = 0 # line0 = header
numEntities=0
targetLines = []

with open(file_entVecs_txt,'r') as fp:
    header = fp.readline() # header

    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if line == '': #EOF
            break
        line_no += 1

        isLatinFlag = True
        for i_l, char in enumerate(line):
            if not isLatin(char): # Care about entity that is Latin-only
                isLatinFlag = False
                break
            if char==' ': # reached separator
                ent = line[:i_l]
                break

        if not isLatinFlag:
            continue

        # Check for numbers in entity
        if re.search('\d',ent):
            continue

        # Check for entities with subheadings '#' (e.g. 'ENTITY/Stereotactic_surgery#History')
        if re.match('^ENTITY/.*#',ent):
            continue

        targetLines.append(line_no)
        numEntities += 1

# Update header with new metadata
header_new = re.sub('^\d+',str(numEntities),header,count=1)

# Generate the file
txtWrite('',file_entVecs_SHORT_txt)
txtAppend(header_new,file_entVecs_SHORT_txt)

line_no = 0
ptr = 0
with open(file_entVecs_txt,'r') as fp:
    while ptr < len(targetLines):
        target_line_no = targetLines[ptr]

        while (line_no != target_line_no):
            fp.readline()
            line_no+=1

        line = fp.readline()
        line_no+=1
        ptr+=1
        txtAppend(line,file_entVecs_SHORT_txt)
```

**FYI. FAILED ATTEMPT** I tried out @zsozso's method (with the `np.array` modifications suggested by @Taegyung), left it to run overnight for at least 12 hrs, it was still stuck at getting new words from the restricted set...). This is perhaps because I have a lot of entities... But my text-file method works within an hour.

**FAILED CODE**

```
# [FAILED] Stuck at Building new vocab...
def restrict_w2v(w2v, restricted_word_set):
    new_vectors = []
    new_vocab = {}
    new_index2entity = []
    new_vectors_norm = []

    print('Building new vocab..')

    for i in range(len(w2v.vocab)):

        if (i%int(1e6)==0) and (i!=0):
            print(f'working on {i}')

        word = w2v.index2entity[i]
        vec = np.array(w2v.vectors[i])
        vocab = w2v.vocab[word]
        vec_norm = w2v.vectors_norm[i]
        if word in restricted_word_set:
            vocab.index = len(new_index2entity)
            new_index2entity.append(word)
            new_vocab[word] = vocab
            new_vectors.append(vec)
            new_vectors_norm.append(vec_norm)

    print('Assigning new vocab')
    w2v.vocab = new_vocab
    print('Assigning new vectors')
    w2v.vectors = np.array(new_vectors)
    print('Assigning new index2entity, index2word')
    w2v.index2entity = new_index2entity
    w2v.index2word = new_index2entity
    print('Assigning new vectors_norm')
    w2v.vectors_norm = np.array(new_vectors_norm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as in zsozso's answer, but for Gensim 4:

```py
def restrict_w2v(w2v, restricted_word_set):
    new_index_to_key = []
    new_key_to_index = {}
    new_vectors = []
    for ind, word in enumerate(w2v.index_to_key):
        if word in restricted_word_set:
            new_key_to_index[word] = len(new_index_to_key)
            new_index_to_key.append(word)
            new_vectors.append(w2v.vectors[ind])
    w2v.index_to_key = new_index_to_key
    w2v.key_to_index = new_key_to_index
    w2v.vectors = np.array(new_vectors)
```

Usage:

```
restricted_words = ...
vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(input_file)
restrict_w2v(vectors, restricted_words)
vectors.save_word2vec_format(output_file)
```

Checked and it works for me (Gensim 4.3.1)

Answer (score 1):

> But when I want to generate the similar words, it should only come
> from a subset of domain specific word.

You can use `most_similar_to_given` to get the most similar word, which comes from a set of your choice. The method uses cosine similarity under the hood.

**Example**

```py
import gensim.downloader

w2v = gensim.downloader.load('glove-twitter-50')
w2v.most_similar_to_given("hotel", ["plane", "house", "penguin"]) # yieldshouse
```