# Is there a way to remove a word from a KeyedVectors vocab?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, embedding, glove

I need to remove an invalid word from the vocab of a "gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors".

I tried to remove it using `del model.vocab[word]`, if I print the `model.vocab` the word disappeared, but when I run `model.most_similar` using other words the word that I deleted is still appearing as similar. 
So how can I delete a word from `model.vocab` in a way that affect the `model.most_similar` to not bring it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a word completely from a Word2Vec model in gensim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941648/how-to-remove-a-word-completely-from-a-word2vec-model-in-gensim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no existing method supporting the removal of individual words.

A quick-and-dirty workaround might be to, at the same time as removing the `vocab` entry, noting the `index` of the existing vector (in the underlying large vector array), and also changing the string in the `kv_model.index2entity` list at that index to some plug value (like say, `'***DELETED***'`).

Then, after performing any `most_similar()`, discard any entries matching `'***DELETED***'`.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to:

[How to remove a word completely from a Word2Vec model in gensim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941648/how-to-remove-a-word-completely-from-a-word2vec-model-in-gensim)

1. Possible method 1: I solve it by editing the text model file itself.
2. Possible method 2: Refer to @zsozso's answer. (Though I didn't get
   it to

work).